# Conditional SubStr

Tags: oracle11g, substr

Working with a CLOB field that contains any number of pairs of fields/values.  The pair is always in the format of "fieldname":"value".

Each record may or may not contain the "street" field, so I need to check if it exists, and if so, return the value.

How can I select the street value from the following character string?

```
{"dob":"08/08/2000","gender":"F","fedethnicity":"0","race_W":"Y","street":"1234 Main St","city":"Denver"}
```

Desired result:  1234 Main St

Comment: Cant you process the JSON in your application

Comment: @Mihai - No, I'm writing a straight sql-based report to be run from sql-developer.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to get your value:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE('{"dob":"08/08/2000","gender":"F","fedethnicity":"0","race_W":"Y","street":"1234 Main St","city":"Denver"}',
                  '.*street":"(.+?)".*',
                  '\1') "The street" FROM DUAL
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3263)

The regex get anything between  `street":"` and `"`